# Does opencv have a constexpr vector or matrix container?

Tags: c++, opencv, constexpr

I would like to do something like this for example:

```
constexpr std::array<cv::Vec3b, 6> COLORS {
    cv::Vec3b(0, 255, 0), // green
    cv::Vec3b(255, 0, 0), // blue
    cv::Vec3b(0, 0, 255), // red
    cv::Vec3b(0, 255, 255), // yellow
    cv::Vec3b(255, 0, 255), // magenta
    cv::Vec3b(255, 255, 0) // cyan
}
```

However, `cv::Vec3b` cannot be made constexpr, is there support for constexpr containers in opencv? Or another way around this?

Compiler error:

```
error: the type ‘const std::vector<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3> >’ of ‘constexpr’ variable ‘COLORS’ is not literal
 };
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the state of OpenCV source code for branches up to 4.10 and 5.0pre there is not support for constexpr classes. In fact a constexpr-able class would need a constructor that is declared constexpr, and it seems that there are not such classes yet. A good candidate would be Scalar, which is, according to the documentation and comment on the file opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core
/types.hpp, used for pixel values.

> /** @brief Template class for a 4-element vector derived from Vec.
>
> Being derived from Vec<_Tp, 4> , Scalar_ and Scalar can be used
> just as typical 4-element vectors. In addition, they can be converted
> to/from CvScalar . The type Scalar is widely used in OpenCV to pass
> pixel values.
> */

A constexpr constructor allows a class to be constructed at compile time and be used in a constexpr context.